# Does $\det(A + B) = \det(A) + \det(B)$ hold?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Well considering two $n \times n$ matrices does the following hold true:
$$\det(A+B) = \det(A) + \det(B)$$
Can there be said anything about $\det(A+B)$?

If $A/B$ are symmetric (or maybe even of the form $\lambda I$) - can then things be said?

Comment: While this is a natural question to ask once you encounter the determinant, did you try any examples at all?

Comment: It would be a good exercise to determine for which matrices, the identity $\det(A+b)=\det(A)+\det(B)$ holds. I think that it would work for rather few of them.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: well at the fear of everyone calling me arrogant: no - but even so I would've asked this question. In my studies I figured the major drawback I have is "proving things". during tentamns 75% of the questions simply are to falsify/prove statements like these. It is also the thing I have most difficulty with (how to start it, what direction to go). I hope by thinking of questions myself & finding/seeing proofs I can train this.

Comment: But you are expected to think a bit about things before asking questions. Sure, part of the question would still make sense to ask, but you would probably have known that the equality does not hold in general, and people might be focusing more on the more tricky part of the question.

Comment: @paul23 Working out some small, concrete examples is often the first step in figuring out how to prove something.

Comment: In dimension $2$, you have the identity $\mathrm{det}(A+B) +\mathrm{tr}(AB) = \mathrm{det}(A) +\mathrm{det}(B) + \mathrm{tr}(A) \mathrm{tr}(B)$, but even this is false when the dimension is $3$ or higher. Have a look [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1267700/meaning-of-the-identity-detab-texttrab-deta-detb-texttra).

Comment: By [Minkowski determinant inequality](https://mathoverflow.net/a/65430), for symmetric positive definite matrices $A$ and $B$ of order $n\times n$, we have $\det(A+B)^{1/n}\ge\det(A)^{1/n}+\det(B)^{1/n}$.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This does not hold true in general. For even $n$, let $A=-B$ and $\det(A) > 0$, so $\det(A+B)=0 < \det(A)+\det(B)$. Now, consider $A=B$. We have $\det(A+B)=\det(2A)=2^n \det(A) > 2 \det(A)=\det(A)+\det(B)$ for $n>1$ and $\det(A)>0$. Thus, either inequality can hold.

Answer (score 18):

In general, you can't expect a formula for $\det(A+B)$. But sometimes, when you're lucky, you can use the [Matrix Determinant Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma), which says the following:

$$\det(A+uv^T)=(1+v^TA^{-1}u)\det(A),$$

where $A$ is an invertible matrix and $v^TA^{-1}u$ is interpreted as a scalar. Therefore, if $A$ is invertible, and you can write $B$ as $uv^T$ for two vectors $u,v$, then now you have a formula.
One could also note that $\det(uv^T)$ is always 0.

---

If you're looking for a matrix operation which is well-behaved with respect to matrix addition, look for the [trace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_%28linear_algebra%29).

Answer (score 16):

No, there is no such law. Playing with simple matrices gives counterexamples, e.g.

$$\det\left(\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\right)=\det\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}=1,$$
but
$$\det\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}+
\det\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}=0+0=0.$$

Answer (score 6):

Take $A=I_n=B$. Then $\det(A+B)=\det(2I_n)=2^n\det(I_n)=2^n$ and $\det(A)+\det(B)=1+1 = 2$ so for $n>1$, your equality does not hold, at least for these matrices. And for $n=1$, since the determinant is the only element of the matrix, we do have your equality. So $$\boxed{\Big[\forall A,B \in M_n\left(\Bbb R\right), \det(A+B)=\det(A)+\det(B)\Big]\iff n  = 1\ }$$

Comment: Your boxed in statement isn't completely correct. You mean $n=1 \Rightarrow [\dots]$. It's not if and only if.

Comment: @nayrb : I added brackets but no, I mean $\iff$. If you have the equality for all matrices, you have it for both matrix equal to $I_n$ so $n=1$ and if $n=1$ then you get the equality for all matrices. Or have I made a mistake somewhere?

Comment: I'm sorry, I must have confused the definition of $M_n(R)$. Is $M_n(R) = \{\lambda I_n \in R^{n \times n}\;|\lambda \in R\}$?

Comment: Okay, take this example. If $A = [[1, 0],[0, 0]]$ and $B = I_2 - B$, then $\det(A+B)=\det(I)=1$ but $\det(A)=\det(B) = 0$. So the space $M_n$ cannot be all real matrices, or even non singular ones.

Comment: The second equation should read $B=I_2-A$.

Comment: I still don't get it. I think we agree on the $\Leftarrow$ par and for the other part, $\left[\forall A,B \in M_n\left(\Bbb R\right), \det(A+B)=\det(A)+\det(B)\right]\implies \det(I_n+I_n)=\det(I_n)+\det(I_n)\implies 2^n=2\implies n=1$

Comment: What is $M_n(R)$?

Comment: The set of all matrices.

Comment: I understand now. Yes, of course. Sorry, missed the quantifier!

Answer (score 5):

Although the determinant function is not linear in general, I have a way to construct matrices $A$ and $B$ such that $\det(A + B) = \det(A) + \det(B)$, where neither $A$ nor $B$ contains a zero entry and all three determinants are nonzero:

Suppose $A = [a_{ij}]$ and $B = [b_{ij}]$ are 2 x 2 real matrices.  Then $\det(A + B) = (a_{11} + b_{11})(a_{22} + b_{22}) - (a_{12} + b_{12})(a_{21} + b_{21})$  and  $\det(A) + \det(B) = (a_{11} a_{22} - a_{12} a_{21}) + (b_{11} b_{22} - b_{12} b_{21})$.

These two determinant expressions are equal if and only if

$a_{11} b_{22} + b_{11} a_{22} - a_{12} b_{21} - b_{12} a_{21}
= $ $\det \left[ 
\begin{array}{cc}
a_{11} & a_{12}\\
b_{21} & b_{22}
\end{array} \right]$
+
$\det \left[ 
\begin{array}{cc}
b_{11} & b_{12}\\
a_{21} & a_{22}
\end{array} \right]$
= 0.

Therefore, if we choose any nonsingular 2 x 2 matrix $ A = [a_{ij}]$ with nonzero entries and then create $B = [b_{ij}]$ such that $b_{11} = - a_{21}, b_{12} = - a_{22}, b_{21} = a_{11},$ and $b_{22} = a_{12}$, we have solved our problem.  For example, if we take
$$A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4
\end{bmatrix}
\quad
\text{and}\quad
B =
\begin{bmatrix}
-3 & -4 \\
1 & 2\end{bmatrix}
,$$

then $\det(A) = -2, \det(B) = -2, $  and  $\det(A + B) = -4$, as required.

Comment: how do you generalize this to large matrix?

Comment: Right now, I don't know how to generalize this.

Comment: what you have is a cool idea I think you should work on to generalize