# What is, in dimension $3$, the identity $\det(A+B+C)$? Here, A,B,C are just diagonal matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

In dimension $2$, we have the identity

$$\det(A+B) + \mbox{tr}(AB) = \det(A) + \det(B) + \mbox{tr}(A) \mbox{tr}(B)$$

but this is false when the dimension is $3$ or higher. So, we need that when dimension is $3$:

$$\det(A+B+C)=?$$

Comment: A,B,C are just diagonal matrices.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1267700/meaning-of-the-identity-detab-texttrab-deta-detb-texttra) for links with $n=3$.

Comment: @ErhanGüler If they are diagonal, why didn't you include such important information in the question itself?