# On the determinant of a sum: when does $\det(A+B)=\det(A)+\det(B)$ hold?

Tags: determinant

When does $\det(A+B)=\det(A)+\det(B)$ hold?

Is there necessary and sufficient condition?

Comment: Related: [Does det(A+B)=det(A)+det(B) hold?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/466043/does-deta-b-deta-detb-hold).

Comment: @dxiv may be but only one post there (by PolyaPal) is relevant.

Comment: It *is* related (and I didn't say *duplicate*). [One of the answers](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/466058/291201) appears to provide a certain sufficient condition.

Comment: @dxiv not that is not relevant (only Polayapal's is relevant).

Comment: An obvious case is: When the dimension is $1$ (that is, the matrices consist of just one number each). Another obvious case: If one of the two matrices is the zero matrix. A less obvious case: $A$ and $B$ are upper triangular matrices, and one of them has only zeros on the diagonal. I don't think those cases are exhaustive.

Comment: Think of $\det(A)$ as the (oriented volume) of the set
$$
A ( \mbox{the unit cube} ).
$$
So, start in 2 dimensions and try to come up with transformations $A$ and $B$ such that the equality holds; i.e., specifically, such that the vector sum of the sets $A ( \mbox{the unit cube} )$ and $B ( \mbox{the unit cube} )$ gives a set whose volume equals
$$
\mbox{vol}[A ( \mbox{the unit cube} ) ] + \mbox{vol}[B ( \mbox{the unit cube} ) ].
$$
My intuition is that this additivity is rather an exception than the rule.

Answer (score 1):

IT IS NOT AN ANSWER.

It is a long comment to show that problem in arbitrary dimension is far from trivial.
If we set simplified case: $B = I$, then: 
$$
n = 2: \det(I + A) = 1 + \det(A) + Tr(A)
$$$$
n = 3: \det(I + A) = 1 + \det(A) + Tr(A) + \frac{Tr^2(A) - Tr(A^2)}{2}
$$$$
n = 4: \det(I + A) = 1 + \det(A) + Tr(A) + \frac{Tr^2(A) - Tr(A^2)}{2} + \frac{Tr^3(A) - 3Tr(A)Tr(A^2) + 2Tr(A^3)}{6}
$$
General sequence comes from relation between determinant and exponent of the trace of the matrix logarithm. 
I doubt that there is a trivial solution in general case.