# Matrix of $0$'s and $1$'s

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, inverse

Let $n \geqslant 2$ be a positive integer. Write $v_i$ for the vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with entry $0$ at the $i$th coordinate and entry $1$ at every other coordinate. Is $\{v_i\}_{i=1}^n$ linearly independent?

It looks like, according to the matrix calculator, that:

\begin{equation*}
\det [v_1^T, \cdots, v_n^T] = (-1)^{n-1}(n-1)
\end{equation*}

But How do I prove it?

Comment: Have you tried proving it by induction?

Comment: The sum of all the rows is $R = [(n-1)\, (n-1)\, \cdots\, (n-1)]$; we can divide by $n-1$ to get a row of ones. Now consider the difference of every row with $R$.

Comment: I did try. But it does not work out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $e \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a column vector of ones, and let $I$ be the $n\times n$ identity matrix. Then
$$
\det(ee^T - I) = (-1)^n \det(I - ee^T) = (-1)^n(1+(-e)^TI^{-1}e)\det(I) = (-1)^n(1-n),
$$

where the second equality uses the Matrix Determinant Lemma I've found in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/466058).

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is exactly what Theophile's comment said...
We can prove it by showing that these vectors span the whole space $\mathbb{R}^n$, because there is exactly $n$ of them so they would have to be the base, which means that they are also independent. Firstly, sum up all the vectors $v_i$ to get $(n-1)\cdot u$, where the vector $u$ has all coordinates equal to $1$. This shows that $u$ is spanned by your vectors. Now substract each of your vectors from $u$: $u-v_i$ to get a vector which has all coordinates equal to $0$ ecxept the $i$-th coordinate, which is $1$. This shows that $u-v_i=e_i$, and vectors $e_i$ (the base vectors) span the whole space.

Answer (score 0):

The matrix $J_n$ with all entries equal to $1$ has one eigenvalue equal to $n$ and the other $n-1$ eigenvalues are zero. [See this link, for example.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217521/what-are-the-eigenvalues-of-matrix-that-have-all-elements-equal-1)

The matrix in question is $J_n-I_n$, where $I_n$ is the $n \times n$ identity matrix. The eigenvalues of $J_n$ are shifted by $1$, which leads to the determinant in question.